# ClassNotFoundException when Lambda Function gets invoced

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, classloader, classnotfoundexception

after uploading the Spring Cloud Function to AWS Lambda and testing it, I get:

```
Class not found: example.Hello: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
```

But I don´t have any `Hello` class in my Packages and no String "Hello" is used in Project(I used the Eclipse Search).

How to find the root cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update [Lambda's Function Code](https://github.com/amazon-archives/legacy-skill-samples-java/issues/6)

> In Lambda, under Function Code, where you specify Handler Info, instead of 'example.Hello', you need to replace that with your own Request Handler.

> This link shows how you would do that in AWS Lambda Setup instruction 9. In this example, handler info is 'com.amazon.asksdk.helloworld.HelloWorldSpeechletRequestStreamHandler' and that's what you would be replacing instead of 'example.Hello'